# Install SyliusWebBundle on existing symfony 2 project

Tags: symfony, sylius

I already have a complete symfony 2.3 project and want to add cart and sale system on it with Sylius bundles. Sylius Cart Bundle and Sale Bundle use SyliusWebBundle and SyliusMoneyBundle. [Sylius documents](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/guide/installation.html) explain about installing a new Sylius project but not including Sylius to existing system. is there any way to install SyliusWebBundle and SyliusMoneyBundle on symfony 2 project?

Answer (score 3):

You can install any of the bundles to your project using composer, just like you would any other symfony2 bundles.

You can find a list of the sylius bundles on the [Packigist site](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=sylius).
The [web bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/web-bundle) can be installed to your current project by simply typing, in your projects root dir:

```
composer require sylius/web-bundle
```

you will be prompted to select the version. "dev-master" is probably what you want.

Note: Depending on your setup the command you run might be

```
php composer.phar require sylius/web-bundle
```

If your not familiar with [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) it's worth the time to look it up :).

[Money bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/money-bundle):

```
php composer.phar require sylius/money-bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

There are documentations for each bundles of Sylius such as this for [CartBundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html) and this for [SaleBundle](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusSalesBundle/installation.html)

Comment: yes, but these bundles use SyliusWebBundle and SyliusMoneyBundle which are missed!!

Comment: Both bundles are after last refactoring in main repository:
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/MoneyBundle
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle